# Distribution of Variables

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

I was annoyed the other day when I got a point off in math class because I didn't distribute the factors of my function.

That is, I put (x+2)(x-3) when I should have put x^2 - x - 6.

Your job is to write a program that takes a string with the expression and convert it to the expanded form so I don't miss future points.

### Rules

- Any letters within the lowercase English alphabet can be used as "x" (for example: (a+1)(c+3)).
- All exponents in answer must be in the form (variable)^n where n is the power
- variables can be assumed to be 1 character long. That is, ab == a * b
- Your answer should not contain the "*" character
- The spaces before and after a + or - must be present. Otherwise, no spaces are permitted, except for trailing spaces.
- You must account for exponents outside of parentheses, so (x+1)^n.

### Specifications

- You may create a program or function that takes a string parameter
- Your program must output the correct expression to STDOUT or a text file
- You may assume that all factors will be surrounded by parentheses. For example, x(x+1) will always be (x)(x+1).
- There will never be any other operation besides multiplication between parenthesis. This will never happen: (x)+(x+1).
- You may assume there will never be any nested parentheses/exponents.
- Order of the resulting expression should be highest exponents first, as per usual math standards. Otherwise, order does not matter.
- You may assume single digit exponents
- Built in expansion libraries/functions are not allowed, as the comments mention below

### Examples

```
(x+1)(x+2) --> x^2 + 3x + 2
(a)(a-4) --> a^2 - 4a
(c+1)^3 --> c^3 + 3c^2 + 3c  + 1
(a+1)(f-2) --> af - 2a + f - 2
(x-2)(x+4)(x-5)(x+10) --> x^4 + 7x^3 - 48x^2 - 140x + 400
(x+a+c)(b+g) --> xb + xg + ab + ag + cb + cg
(r+4)^2(b) --> br^2 + 8br + 16b
```

This is code-golf, so shortest program wins!

### Bonus

-25 bytes to anyone who makes their program compatible with [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)

Comment: This would be pretty easy in languages like Matlab and Mathematica that have algebraic simplification built in.

Comment: Seems too easy in some languages: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expand.html

Comment: *usual math standards*? I must have skipped that class...

Comment: You might want to disallow ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​using built-in CAS functions to make this challenge a bit more fair for all languages.

Comment: I voted for closing as duplicate, but in fact the requirements are quite different, so I'm not so sure.

Comment: I think the rules currently allow `x^2 - 3x + 2x - 6` as output.

Comment: About the order by high exponent first, what if there are 2 variables (x^2+xy+y^2? x^2+y^2+xy? ). And 3 or more?

Comment: `The spaces before and after a + or - must be present`. So (1-x)(x-1) -> " - x^2 + 2x - 1" (ugly). Space before but not after would be better: " -x^2 +2x -1"

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (E6) 834

While waiting for some clarification by OP, I start recycling my answer from  [this other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33248/basic-algebraic-expansion)
It's more than what is required here, so it could be golfed more.
I have modified the spacing and added sorting by higher exponent (of any variable).

```
G=x=>x.replace(/\d/g,n=>' '.repeat(n-2)).length,
K=x=>Object.keys(x).sort((a,b)=>G(b)-G(a)),
A=(p,q,s,t,c)=>[(c=(s+1)*q[t]+~~p[t])?p[t]=c:delete(p[t])for(t in q)],
M=(p,q,t,c,o,u,f,r,v={})=>([A(v,(r={},[(c=p[f]*q[t])&&(r[o={},(u=f+t)&&(u.match(/[a-z]\^?\d*/ig).map(x=>o[x[0]]=~~o[x[0]]+(~~x.slice(2)||1)),K(o,u=k).map(i=>u+=o[i]>1?i+'^'+o[i]:i)),u]=c)for(f in p)],r),k)for(t in q)],v),
E=(p,n)=>--n?M(p,E(p,n)):p,
O=n=>{for(l=0;h(o=s.pop())>=h(n);)a=w.pop(b=w.pop()),o=='*'?a=M(a,b):o>d?a=E(a,b[k]):A(a,b,o),w.push(a);s.push(o,n)},
X=e=>(l=k='',w=[],s=[d='@'],h=o=>'@)+-*^('.indexOf(o),
(e+')').match(/\D|\d+/g).map(t=>(u=h(t))>5?(l&&O('*'),s.push(d)):u>1?O(t):~u?s.pop(s.pop(O(t)),l=1):(l&&O('*'),l=1,w.push(v={}),t<d?v[k]=t|0:v[t]=1)),
K(p=w.pop()).map(i=>(k+=(c=p[i])>1?s+c+i:c<-1?c+i:(c-1?'-':s)+(i||1),s=' + ')),k.replace(/-/g,' - ')||0)
```

**Test** in FireFox/FireBug console

```
;["(x+1)(x+2)","(a)(a-4)","(c+1)^3","(a+1)(f-2)","(x-2)(x+4)(x-5)(x+10)","(x+a+c)(b+g)","(r+4)^2(b)"]
.map(x => console.log(x + " -> " + X(x)))
```

*Output*

```
(x+1)(x+2) -> x^2 + 3x + 2
(a)(a-4) -> a^2 - 4a
(c+1)^3 -> c^3 + 3c^2 + 3c + 1
(a+1)(f-2) -> af + f - 2a - 2
(x-2)(x+4)(x-5)(x+10) -> x^4 + 7x^3 - 48x^2 - 140x + 400
(x+a+c)(b+g) -> xb + ab + cb + xg + ag + cg
(r+4)^2(b) -> r^2b + 8rb + 16b
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica <strike>11-25=-14</strike> 40-25=15 characters

Really too easy in this language:

```
f=TraditionalForm@Expand@ToExpression@#&
```

Usage:

```
f["(x+2)(x-3)"]
```

Output:

x<sup>2</sup> - x - 6

And it's even shorter if you allow input that isn't a string (and don't care about term order):

```
f=Expand@ToExpression@#&
```

Used as follows for the same output:

```
f[(x+2)(x-3)]
```

Mathematica can natively support complex numbers.

EDIT: technically this answer fails because it will take ab (without spaces) as a single variable instead of a*b as per the rules.

EDIT2:Changed so it will output in the required order

Comment: I thought about posting this as well. I don't think the `ab` is a problem, because it doesn't seem to be part of the input. However, (and this is the reason I didn't post it) the order of the terms needs to be the opposite.

Comment: Good point, ab will be more difficult to solve, but at least the order of the terms can be fixed.

Comment: Oh, actually the rules changed since I saw the challenge: "Built in expansion libraries/functions are not allowed." So this approach isn't allowed anyway.

Comment: Ah dang, missed that... whoops. well, maybe I'll update it later to a form that doesn't use it, but I don't think I will.